# Jackson: empty nested entities when using filtering

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have code to serialiaze only certain fields in an object, using [filterOutAllExcept](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html#filterOutAllExcept(java.util.Set)):

```
FilterProvider newF = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter(
    "filter properties by name",
    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(fields2Show)
);
writer = mapper.writer(newF);
```

When `fiels2Show` is `null`, above code is not run, filter is not applied and I get nested objects correctly, something like this:

```
[ {
  "phone" : null,
  "duration" : 1200000,
  "unique_id" : "376_1244",
  "id" : 1244,
  "record_types" : [ {
    "customer_id" : 376,
    "max_age" : 20,
    "min_age" : 10,
    "id" : 15351,
    "entity_type" : "CalendarRecordType"
  }, {
    "customer_id" : 376,
    "max_age" : 30,
    "min_age" : 10,
    "id" : 15352,
    "entity_type" : "CalendarRecordType"
  } ]
} ]
```

But when `fields2Show` is set, somehow things go terribly wrong. Let `fields2Show` be a `Set<String>` which contains just one string "record_types". Then I get result like this:

```
[ {
  "record_types" : [ { }, { } ]
} ]
```

Why?

Comment: the result is exactly as expected: everything got filtered out except "record_types". what's the problem?

Comment: @sharonbn The problem is that "record_types" is now array of empty objects, not serialized. Actually, useless.

Answer (score 3):

The javadoc for [SimpleBeanPropertyFilter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html) is quite clear:

> Simple PropertyFilter implementation that only uses property name to
>   determine whether to serialize property as is, or to filter it out.

It is obvious that the filter ignores property hierarchy. The description goes on:

> Use of this class as the base implementation for any custom
>   PropertyFilter implementations is strongly encouraged, because it can
>   provide default implementation for any methods that may be added in
>   PropertyFilter (as unfortunate as additions may be).

Which hints that if one wants to extend the default simplistic behavior, then one should extend this class and create a custom filter.

Examining the javadoc of the abovementioned class, I came to the folowing conclusions:

1. The `filterOutAllExcept()` method is a factory method that returns an implementation that overrides the abstract `include()` methods. These methods have access to one property, and not the full bean (or POJO) object.
2. However, the class also contains a [`serializeAsField()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/impl/SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.html#serializeAsField(java.lang.Object,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.PropertyWriter)) method that recevies the object and can deduce the hierarchy of properties.

In conclusion, I think you should write a new class that extends the simple filter and implement `serializeAsField()` in order to produce required result.

Comment: Oh. Doesn't look a fast and easy solution. Anyway, maybe someone will get interested in implementing.